# How to get OneSignal playerId (userId) in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, push-notification, onesignal

How to get playerId of a user inside the flutter app?. Player Id can be found in One signal website but i want that inside the flutter app and want to store it to send the notification to particular user.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is my goto function for initating onesignal

```
  Future<void> initOneSignal(BuildContext context) async {
    /// Set App Id.
    await OneSignal.shared.setAppId(SahityaOneSignalCollection.appID);

    /// Get the Onesignal userId and update that into the firebase.
    /// So, that it can be used to send Notifications to users later.̥
    final status = await OneSignal.shared.getDeviceState();
    final String? osUserID = status?.userId;
    // We will update this once he logged in and goes to dashboard.
    ////updateUserProfile(osUserID);
    // Store it into shared prefs, So that later we can use it.
    Preferences.setOnesignalUserId(osUserID);

    // The promptForPushNotificationsWithUserResponse function will show the iOS push notification prompt. We recommend removing the following code and instead using an In-App Message to prompt for notification permission
    await OneSignal.shared.promptUserForPushNotificationPermission(
      fallbackToSettings: true,
    );

    /// Calls when foreground notification arrives.
    OneSignal.shared.setNotificationWillShowInForegroundHandler(
      handleForegroundNotifications,
    );

    /// Calls when the notification opens the app.
    OneSignal.shared.setNotificationOpenedHandler(handleBackgroundNotification);
  }
```

Comment: If this helps please mark it as answer :)

Comment: Hi I would like to ask.. I am currently install app that consist of notification in emulator and it works perfectly, and now I would like to install it in real device but the status subscribed is always false, is there a way to subscribe new device ?

Answer (score 1):

For OneSignal 5.0.0 and above
read more about the new updates and migration guide [here](https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Flutter-SDK/blob/user_model/main/MIGRATION_GUIDE.md)

```dart
Future<void> initOneSignal() async {
  OneSignal.Debug.setLogLevel(
    kDebugMode ? OSLogLevel.verbose : OSLogLevel.none,
  );

  OneSignal.initialize("appId");

  final id = OneSignal.User.pushSubscription.id;

  if (id != null) {
    SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((value) {
      value.setString(Preferences.oneSignalUserId, id);
    });
  }

  await OneSignal.Notifications.requestPermission(true);
}
```